# PHP SQL row counting or Numbering

Tags: php, sql

I have code as shown below. What i want to do  is either number each echo row, or get a total of how many rows are filtered according to the code below.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="****"; // Mysql username 
$password="****"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="****"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE dealer= 'Panzer Protection'");

?>
      <?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FF0000"><center>
          <? echo $rows['member_msisdn']; ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="#FF0000"><center>
          <? echo $rows['member_name']; ?></td>
        <td bgcolor="#FF0000"><? echo $rows['dealer']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="control_clientinfo.php?member_id=    
<? echo $rows['member_id']; ?>" class="update">Look Up</a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
}
?>
```

So basically i need to count the rows displayed for the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of rows using `mysql_num_rows()` function

```
echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

As a side note Stop using `mysql_*` because its deprecated start using `Mysqli` OR `PDO`.

Comment: Thanks we busy sorting the basic's then will change all the code to Mysqli, where would i place echo mysql_num_rows($result); in the table and as PHP <? echo mysql_num_rows($result); ?>

Comment: @TrevorAckermann Place it above `while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_num_rows($result) to get the total number of rows and use a simple count variable in the while-loop to get the number of each row.